# XSLT for summing Number column where there are cells with no value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, aggregation, number

This is akin to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/xslt-for-summing-a-column-in-a-data-view-web-part) but I couldn't get the suggested `sumAll` function to work.  I also have several different columns to sum and it just seems silly to have a separate template for each column I want to sum.  I have a column where not all rows have a value.  I want to sum the rows that do have values.  I have tried the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($nodeset/@MyField[string-length(@MyField) &gt; 0])" />
```

This seems like it should work.  However, I get 0 as the total.  The very same data view shows individual rows below the total with values like 300, 160, etc., so 0 is obviously an incorrect total.  I have tried wrapping `@MyField` in `number()`, but I end up getting `NaN` as the total then.  All the examples I've seen online talk about `translate()` and dealing with British-style decimals, but I'm working with American-style decimals and I don't see any individual values with commas.

How can I sum this column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive that this will answer your entire question as I'm not certain about your use of decimals etc.

Try replacing the string-length(@MyField) with string-length(.) :

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($nodeset/@MyField[string-length(.) &gt; 0])" />
```

I've tested this quickly and this returns a value where your expression returned 0, so it should go a long way to solving your problems.

Comment: That got it!  I'd vote you up but I don't have the reputation for it.  :(